# connection error while using php and sql server 2008

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, network-programming, server

Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

as i establish connection between my computer and remote machine using "php" and sql server 2008 respectively. i got this error.

```
    <?php
    $servername = "";
   $username = "";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "complaint";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

 ?>
```

Comment: <?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "complaint";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

?>

Comment: Mysqli is not for connections to SQL Server. For that check the SQL Server Driver for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You must have a defined servername, username and password. If the server is local than use "localhost" if it is a remote server use IP "X.X.X.X"

Comment: <?php
      $servername = "localhost:88";
     $username = "root";
     $password = "";
    $dbname = "complaint";
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

?>
-------------------------------------------------------------------------